# removing listener in addListener

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, listener

I'm programming a node.js Facebook-like chat plugin for my website and I've been having issues with the server crashing after a day. I think the issue is that my session.event.addListener is clogging up the listener array resulting in the crash. Here is the code where I add the listener:

```
this.events.addListener('update', o_.bind(function(package) {
    if(this.clear != 0){
        delete this.sessions[this.clear];
        break; //will this break stop a listener from being added?
    }
    var _package = package.toJSON();
    if(package.type == 'status' && package.status == 'offline') {
        var sids = Object.keys(this.sessions), sid, sess;
        for(sid in this.sessions) {
            sess = this.sessions[sid];
            if(sess.data('username') == package.username) {
                if(sess.listeners.length)
                    sess.send(200, {type: 'goodbye'});
                delete this.sessions[sid];
                break; //here too
            }
        }
    }
}, this));
};
```

Will the breaks within the if statements allow a listener from not being added because I'm not sure if it's working.
Thank you!

Comment: What are you trying to do?  By running that statement, you are adding that event listener.  Are you trying to _remove_ the event listener when the event runs (with some conditions)?

Comment: Yea, so pretty much I dont want to add a listener if either of those two statements are true. I added       this.events.removeListener('update',arguments.callee,false); right after the delete call in each of the ifs. I don't think it is working however since my server crashed this morning. Any advice to point me in the right direction is greatly appreciated. Thank you!